# ASP.NET MVC ViewModel and Request Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Greetings!

I need assistance with ASP.NET MVC and the values posted from a form operation (form is inside a Partial View).

On my page to create a User Account, various form fields collect the information. The Partial View is backed by a ViewModel (UserAccountViewModel).

To validate and/or save the information, I need to pass the values of the form to UserAccountService. Back in Java and Struts 1.x, I used the getMap() method of the DynaActionForm, but being an ASP.NET newbie, I'm not sure of the best way to proceed.

On a post operation, are the fields of the ViewModel automatically updated? If that's the case, I could pass the ViewModel to the Service layer (not my preferred solution, but good enough).

Jason

Comment: Jason, please post the code you have tried so far and describe how it's not working for you. Other than that read Steven Sanderson's Pro ASP.NET MVC book by Apress (http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430210079), it will bring you easily up to speed on MVC in no time.

Comment: Lazarus, I haven't written the code yet. I needed to know if I would have to deal with each Request variable separately, or whether there was already a structure I could use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UpdateForm method in .net to have it automatically map the form data to your model based on similar naming.

```
UserAccountViewModel.UpdateForm(Request.Form);
```

UpdateForm will work on pretty much any class with properties, you just need to import the namespace. [Here is a pretty good tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/09/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios.aspx) on form handling in asp.net mvc that uses this method. This sounds like it's a similar method to what you're used to in Java.